# "kill -INT $pid" won't kill process, but ctrl+c will

Tags: bash, unix

I have a basic bash script that prints out its pid, then counts to 100:

```
echo $$
for i in {1..100}
do
    echo $i
    sleep 1
done
```

When I press ctrl+c, while this is running, the program will halt with an exit code of 130. I am trying to send a signal that will simulate a ctrl+c and cause the program to halt and exit with code 130.

When I type "kill -INT " from a different terminal window, nothing happens, though from what I understand, it should be the same as hitting ctrl+c. However, when I type "kill -9 ", I can successfully terminate the program, albeit with a different exit code.  How do I stop my program with an interrupt signal, so it exits with the proper code?

Comment: Can you re-clarify your requirement? The script already exits with code 130 on Ctrl + C. Did you mean you want your script to catch the signal and exit with code other than 130?

Comment: @quantumbutterfly : That `-9` gives you a different exit code, is obvious, because it is a different signal, so the question boils down to why your `kill -INT` is not delivered. Indeed, I can reproduce the case without the need of a whole script: `bash -c 'echo $$; sleep 120'`, and then do a `kill -INT` on the displayed PID. For me, it also does not terminate the process.  If I change it to `bash -c 'trap "echo intreceived" INT; echo $$; sleep 120'` and send the _kill_, I don't even get the output _intreceived_, which  means that the signal was not delivered. No idea why it behaves like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepend process id with dash sign "-"

```
kill -SIGINT -<pid>
```

This will kill the process with exit code 130.

UPD: Why not to use SIGTERM(15) which is send by kill command by default (with no signal number or name)?

Comment: Indeed it works. Can you explain the reason? The _kill_ man page doesn't mention this, and when I do a `kill TERM <pid>`, I do not need a dash in front of the pid.

Comment: @JUSHJUSH Looks like OP is using MacOS and there is no mention of process groups.